# jQuery hover flickers on last element in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, hover, menuitem

I'm using jQuery hover to hover over a list of menu items. The screen flickers when its hovered over the bottom part of the last element in the list.

Here is a link to the website: https://www-stage.reprisedigital.com/

When you hover over the bottom part of the 'Contact' item, the screen flickers.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't flicker for me.

Comment: Pretty simple to know why: The height changes so mouse is over and out and over and out and over and out and over and out.....

Comment: @chrisz Move your mouse a little bit below the 'Contact' item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `height` of

```
<p class="header-text" id="header-text">
    <font color="#00B9AD">Revolutionize</font> 
    the future of digital marketing
</p>
```

toggles between 35px and 45px.